# OOP init trouble

Tags: python, class, oop

```
class BankAccount():
    total_accounts = 0

    def __init__(self, savings_accounts, checking_accounts):
        self.savings_accounts = savings_accounts
        self.checking_accounts = checking_accounts

    def displayCounter1(self):
        print(total_accounts)


class Savings_Accounts(BankAccount):
    savingsBalance = 5000000.00
    def __init__(self, savings_accounts, checking_accounts):
        self.savings_accounts = savings_accounts
        self.checking_accounts = checking_Accounts

class Checking_Accounts(BankAccount):
    checkingsalance = 50000000.00
    def __init__(self, savings_accounts, checking_accounts):
        self.savings_accounts = savings_accounts
        self.checking_accounts = checking_Accounts
    def displayCounter(self):
        print(checkingsalance)
n = Checking_Accounts(BankAccount)
n.displayCounter()
```

Above is my code in command prompt I keep getting an error saying missing 1 required postitional argument

Comment: `Checking_Accounts.__init__` takes two arguments (in addition to self), but `Checking_Accounts(BankAccount)` only provides 1.

Comment: You passed a savings account but not a checking account to your constructor. You declared a constructor that takes two (non-`self`) arguments but you only gave it one.

Comment: " I keep getting an error saying" why don't you post the full error message, including the stack trace?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146. That said, nothing about your code makes much sense and I have no idea what you think a class is or what they are for. I think you need the help of a dedicated instructor, or at least a discussion forum, which this is not.

Answer (score 1):

A few things here

1. Your `Checking_Accounts` takes in 2 arguments (savings_account and checking_accounts) but you only pass in one argument (BankAccount)
2. Since you have the same constructor each time, you don't need to redefine it. Rather you can just `super().__init__(savings_account, checking_accounts)`
3. I think your general class structure is a bit weird. It doesn't really make sense for a BankAccount/Savings_Account/Checking_Accounts to have instance attributes of savings_account and checking_accounts. (but this is not really relevant to the question).
4. I also don't believe you wanted to pass in a BankAccount class to your constructor, but probably an instance of BankAccount? In that case you need to do `BankAccount()`.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting is because all of your classes take multiple arguments (`savings_account` and `checking_account`), but you've only supplied one argument to the `Checking_Accounts` constructor.

It doesn't make sense for the savings and checking account classes to each require parameters that refer to the other -- for that matter, since these two classes do exactly the same thing, it doesn't make sense for them to be two classes!  Here's a version of the code that might get closer to what you're trying to do:

```
class BankAccount:
    def __init__(self, balance):
        self.balance = balance

    def display(self):
        print(self.balance)


class CombinedAccount:
    def __init__(self, savings, checking):
        self.accounts = [savings, checking]

    def display(self):
        print(sum(account.balance for account in self.accounts))


checking = BankAccount(50000000.00)
savings = BankAccount(50000000.00)
checking.display()
savings.display()

combined = CombinedAccount(savings, checking)
combined.display()
```